# How to deploy nextjs into a directory which is not a root directory

Tags: node.js, nginx, webpack, next.js

Recently I learn something about nextjs because I want to make a site which SEO friendly by using React. Everything looks great until I ran into a problem.

It's about how can I deploy nextjs app into a directory which is not a root directory, for example '/next'. I use a simple config for nextjs, use the default node server listen to 3000 port and then use nginx for reverse.

next.config looks like :

[image]

nginx conf :

[image]

When I access localhost:8080/next I got the 404 page which is provided by nextjs and the css or js is also 404. It seems like the config of nextjs or nginx is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current config tells nginx to map urls 1-to-1, that means that `/next/what-ever` will be mapped to `http://localhost:3000/next/what-ever`.

To solve this you need to add an additional slash.

```
server {
  ...
  location /next/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/ // <----  this last slash tells to drop the prefix
  }
}
```

For more info read https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/#passing-a-request-to-a-proxied-server

Answer (score 0):

There is a basePath config now for next.config.js, but unfortunately you can't set it to be relative, ie. `./` or `.`

I have a use case where the SPA is uploaded to a directory at /X-generated/Y-generated/index.html, but I haven't been able to find a translation for this from create-react-app to next.js yet